# Entity Framework 4 code-only reference column name

Tags: entity-framework

I created classes:

```
public class Country
{
  public long CountryId {get;set;}
  public string CountryName {get;set;}
}

public class Profile
{
  public long ProfileId {get;set;}
  public string ProfileName {get;set;}
  public Country Country {get;set;}
}
```

and configuration for Profile:

```
public class ProfileConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<Profile>
{
  public IlluminatiCoreProfileConfiguration()
  {
    Relation(p => p.Country);
  }
}
```

Then I create context and run context.CreateDatabase(). New database contains table Profiles with column Country_CountryId. How can I write configuration for changing column name to "CountryId"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your POCO for Profile:

```
public class Profile
{
    public long ProfileId {get;set;}
    public string ProfileName {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("CountryId")]
    public Country Country {get;set;}
}
```

In your POCO for Country

```
[Table("Country")]
public class Country
{
    [Column(Name = "CountryId")]
    public int CountryId {get;set;}
}
```

This will over write the brain dead Object_Property mapping that EF by default creates.  You can specify this on any table / property to override the actual DB column naming conventions.

EDIT:
I guess the namespace for those annotations would be helpful:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Comment: It was in the version of EF this targeted.  Research a little before tossing a down vote, WHEN this question was answered THIS WAS a valid annotation.  Just because M$ changed it in future versions doesn't make this answer any less valid.